# How transmit power affects power consumption of Wi-Fi router?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, power

I wonder how Transmit Power affects power consumption and heating of my home wireless router. Below you can see a screenshot from router control panel.

[image: transmit power]

I can easily set it to 50% and on Windows 8 it still shows 5/5 signal. But I wanted to know if it has any significant advantages on power consumption or device lifetime. My router is TP-Link TD-W8970 but question is rather about home Wi-Fi routers in general.

Comment: You might actually get some really good answers to this on physics.SE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wi-Fi transmit power is typically limited by government regulations to 1 watt or less. The other components of your wireless router easily use more power than the Wi-Fi transmitters. Even if your AP was continually transmitting packets at 1 watt 24 hours a day for a year, the transmission power would only cost you about one US dollar per year at typical US residential electricity prices.

Any competent AP designer should have designed your AP to not overheat even when running at full power, so running at full power all the time shouldn't hurt longevity, and running at lower power shouldn't improve longevity.

The only real point of turning down the power is to avoid interfering with other users of the 2.4GHz or 5GHz frequency bands.

Comment: +1 :-)  Hi Spiff ! Do you know how much RF power on the average is transmitted from a typical Wi-Fi router, while it's in the **idle** mode; i.e., no active internet connections, no downloads, just beaconing its own SSID, like during night (sleep) time. Assume a max RF transmit power of 30 mW; and take wireless connecton speed at 54 Mbps... I hope you know such RF modulation details..? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Fat32 What's your goal here?

Comment: I want to get an estimate of RF exposure from wi-fi router during idle mode... (I can't measure it,  I have to calculate it, but i don't know its transmission details )

Comment: @Fat32 Even if it was continuously transmitting at 30mW, it's orders of magnitude less EM exposure than even a dimly lit room lit only by the softest of UV-filtered indirect natural daylight. But anyway beacons are usually sent at a rate of slightly less than 10 per second, and are a few hundred bytes each. So let's say 20k to 40k bits per second. At a 1Mbps Tx rate, that's 2-4% duty cycle. At the 54Mbps PHY rate you suggested, that's like 0.0003% - 0.0007% duty cycle. And remember that most of that is absorbed by your walls, furniture, and clothes, so only femtowatts hit your body.

Comment: Yes *other* sources contribute much more energy but at different frequencies. The problem is the guy downstairs who attached a 7/24 wifi on his ceiling directly below my bed !!! I'm measuring -45 dBm radiation from him (my own wifi yields < -60 dBm) and I try to build cheap aliminum folio shield to reflect his radiation back. In the mean time I wanted to know how much during idle (night) time the RF transmission from the wiki AP router. I found similar results to what you say; 3.6 % air-time used by beaconing at 1Mbps; so -50 dBm will further reduce by 14 dBm into -65 dBm avg. Thank you :-)

Comment: @Fat32. -65dBm is less than 1 nanowatt, and this is at a lot lower frequency (thus less risky) than a traditional 4W night light (and visible light is EM "radiation" at a MUCH higher frequency, and thus more dangerous). So your nightlight is absolutely destroying you compared to your neighbor's Wi-Fi.

Comment: Visible light is about 100 THz and cannot penetrate into the body tissues (completely blocked by the skin) and our skins are evolutionaly adapted to day light of much powerful radiation (1 kW/m2). Yet RF range can penetrate into body tissues which are not adapted for such excitations; though the frequency 2.4 GHz is not an **ionizing** one. Yet the continuous exposure to it during sleep can have adverse effects on the brain waves or cell membrane chemistry... It's an area not very well investigated. Very complex issue, mostly psychologic but statistics show insomnia correlation to wifi.

Comment: @Fat32 Those clip-on fingertip pulse-oximeters work by shining light clear through the skin and flesh of your fingertip. Put your hand over a bright flashlight and your hand glows red. So the idea that light doesn't penetrate skin is complete BS.

Comment: ok I shouldn't have said **completely** (100%) blocked as that' not true, but also was not the concern.

Comment: EM interaction with objects is a frequency dependent complex quantum molecular issue. Our skin (and some tissues) is not 100% **opaque** to visible light. They have some little transparency. So if you put a very strong visible light electromagnetic radiation, comparatively a very small part of it will pass through the skin and tissues and you can see it too; as all children once like doing. But, to RF electromagnetic radiation, skin is almost fully **transparent** and all the wave penetrates into the brain passing through the **skull** ( to the **depths** that visible light could not). BS?

Comment: Anyway. Certain electromagnetic waves are passing through the body and brain. That's the problem, and our skin (and tissues also) are **adapted** to day light visible radiation but not to RF radiation; that's what creates my concern.